# DarkaOnline swagger integration in Lumen not registering Swagger\Lume::ServiceProvider

Tags: swagger, lumen, service-provider

I am trying to integrate swagger in mu lumen project. Lumen version is 5.7
In my local system it is working fine, but in server (Ubuntu) I could not follow the command because of memory issue, so I uploaded vendor folder, composer.json and composer.lock files from local to server and I run composer dump-autoload command.

I followed this documentation for swagger integration .

https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/SwaggerLume

Then in my terminal I run php artisan swagger-lume:publish

But I got

> Class 'SwaggerLume\ServiceProvider' not found in Apllication.php line 183

I have configured my bootstrap/app.php file like below befre this

uncommented $app->withFacades(); and added $app->configure('swagger-lume'); before Register container bindings. And I added $app->register(\SwaggerLume\ServiceProvider::class); inside Register Service Providers.

```
<?php

 require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

 try {
  (new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__.'/../'))->load();
 } catch (Dotenv\Exception\InvalidPathException $e) {
//
}

 /*
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | Create The Application
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |
   | Here we will load the environment and create the application instance
   | that serves as the central piece of this framework. We'll use this
   | application as an "IoC" container and router for this framework.
   |
 */

  $app = new Laravel\Lumen\Application(
  realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
  );

  $app->withFacades();

  $app->withEloquent();

  $app->configure('swagger-lume');

 /*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Register Container Bindings
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Now we will register a few bindings in the service container. We will
 | register the exception handler and the console kernel. You may add
 | your own bindings here if you like or you can make another file.
 |
 */

 $app->singleton(
  Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
  App\Exceptions\Handler::class
 );

 $app->singleton(
  Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class,
  App\Console\Kernel::class
);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Middleware
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, we will register the middleware with the application. These can
| be global middleware that run before and after each request into a
| route or middleware that'll be assigned to some specific routes.
|
*/


$app->routeMiddleware([
'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
]);

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Register Service Providers
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Here we will register all of the application's service providers which
 | are used to bind services into the container. Service providers are
 | totally optional, so you are not required to uncomment this line.
 |
```

*/

```
 $app->register(App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class);
 $app->register(\SwaggerLume\ServiceProvider::class);
```